# FIN & RST set in socket communication

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, tcp

There is existing socket communication with TLS 1.2 enabled for which i have included one-way/two-way support , on doing so i have observed frequent reset in socket .
While analyzing the packets using wire shark observed FIN,ACK & RST flag sent which i believe the reason for getting reset or aborting the connection .

My queries:

1. During the socket conversation i believe , at many occasion i observer EOFexcetpion while attempting to readObject(). Can this lead to socket reset or disconnect.
2. In case i want the socket connection to be permanently connected , how can i ignore FIN & RST flag and keep up the socket connection permanent ?
3. Is it efficient whenever socket finds idle then to disconnect . Is it when RST or FIN flag is passed ?

Comment: 1. `EOFException` cannot by itself lead to an RST, but what you do next in response can. 2. You can't: see @jiJmGarrison's answer. 3. (a) Yes it is efficient to lose idle connections, and (b) disconnect causes a FIN, unless you have done something strange like not reading all the pending data.

Comment: @user207421 , what i understand my server code spawns a socket instance with executer services and this in loop to make it recreate in case if if socket get's disconnected .  But what i observe here for some reason server code after sending message socket get's closed and while client trying to readObject() which prematurely throws EOF exception which leads to socket close() , to tackle this issue can i make the socket.shutdown() so that client end will honored to still read before actually close it ? i mean adding socket.shutdown() both server & client side instead of socket.close() ?

Comment: The server doesn't recreate anything. It accepts new connections. `EOFException` means the peer closed the connection prematurely. If it happened in `readObject()` you have done something wrong at the sending end. `shutdown()` isn't required here as far as I can see. You need to post the client code.

Answer (score 2):

> ...how can i ignore FIN & RST flag ...

The simple answer is that you cannot.

The protocol specifies that once you receive FIN the connection is in the process of being dismantled.  You can attempt to do whatever you want, but the sender of the FIN packet is going away regardless of what you do.

The RST flag is sent back to you when you send data to an endpoint that was not expecting a packet from you, i.e. when you tried to ignore FIN.

Keeping a connection open "permanently" requires cooperation from both sides of the connection, and the connection may still fail due to timeouts if the network goes down.

Answer (score -1):

> Is it efficient whenever socket finds idle then to disconnect

yes it is efficient to disconnect or dismantle the socket for idle connections. If idle connections were not dismantled, then as new connections are initiated, the connections (socket connections) continue to remain and consume system resources/memory. Additionally each socket connection is on a new port, so as new connections keep coming in (if your server is busy like a web server for example), you continue to use up tcp ports!
Also there are two different states, FIN_WAIT_1 and FIN_WAIT_2 (refer [RFC 793 for TCP Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#page-21))
So bottom line, it may not be a good idea to continue to have the socket connection to be always or permanently connected- certainly not a good idea for a busy server which is accepting lots of client traffic- the newer accepted connections will continue to remain and consume or use up local tcp ports incrementally as newer connections keep coming in...

Comment: All incoming TCP connections use the same port as the listening socket they were accepted from. FIN_WAIT_1 and FIN_WAIT_2 are port states, not flavours of FIN, which is a segment flag.

Comment: What is correct is that they are port states, not 'flavours' of FIN, which is what the question is about, and which is one bit in a segment header ([RFC 793](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793#page-15)) and therefore cannot possibly have two flavours. Your statement doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes that is correct FIN_WAIT_1 and FIN_WAIT_2 are two states ( as defined in RFC 793, different states as - A connection progresses through a series of states during its lifetime)
FIN-WAIT-1 - represents waiting for a connection termination request from the remote TCP, or an acknowledgment of the connection termination 
request previously sent.   FIN-WAIT-2 - represents waiting for a connection termination request from the remote TCP.  (I will edit the answer to remove the word flavor)

Comment: Yes and the FIN_WAIT and other port states don't actually have anything to do with the question. Your error about the ports remains uncorrected. The only part of this answer that actually answers the question without error is the first two sentences.